# How to get nulls at the top of database query results?

Tags: oracle11g

I make a query with a huge amount of data. It is imporant that I get rows with null values in a specific column at the beginning of results. I want to avoid using ORDER BY because it will certainly make a big performance hit. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: The ***only*** (really: the only) way to get a specific order of rows is to use `order by`. There is no alternative. How do you know it will be a "big performance hit"? Did you try it? What was the result with and without order by? Also: what is "a huge amount of data"?

Comment: Please specify "huge amount" also hard to help you without seeing your query, I'd suggest you actually post your execution plan for the query.